# Maximum value for Nat in michelson

Tags: michelson

Hello what is the maximum value for natrual number in michelson or what a bigmap can handle. I am trying to write a FA1.2 contract and is concerned if there will be a maximum amount an account can hold for balance. For example in solidity there is uint256 (maximum value of 2^256-1 = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935 //78 decimal digits)

Answer (score 3):

There is none (apart from implicit bounds due to gas or storage limit which shouldn’t limit you in practice).